# Creating app data to load at runtime

Tags: ios, persistence

I’m an inexperienced iPhone developer hoping to get a bit of insight into how to create textual application data that will be distributed with my iPhone application.

The use case is simple – I’m creating a tutorial to show the users how to use the app. There will be a set on x tutorials (chapters, if you will) each having y number of steps. Each step contains a set of strings that will get read in and converted to meaningful information. I’d like to be able to load one chapter at a time to minimize overhead. I’d really like to be able to create and edit the text outside of XCode (for obvious reasons). The tutorial text should install with the application and be read when the user starts the tutorial.

There are lots of options – core data, SQL Lite, NSEncoding, etc. It’s a lot to sift through. At this point I’m leaning toward NSEncoding, but it looks like I’d have to write code to create the data – some utility app and that creates the tutorial files offline. That’s not a big deal, but it just makes it hard to maintain. Plus a property list file just seems wrong. And it doesn’t seem like it should be this hard.

Anyway, I’m looking for some advice on the most pain-free way to organize and load a bunch of text strings that are created outside of the app.

I’m also confused on how to package the text files for deployment, so if you know of a good tutorial I’d appreciate the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a plist file would be a good approach to this- it would let you edit outside of Xcode and organize the data in a coherent way. Another great aspect of the plist is you could have an array of "chapters" and in that array have another array of "steps"; then when you load the plist you can search through it for which chapter and step you want. Loading the plist on the iPhone is very simple- it transitions to NSArrays or NSDictionaries very easily.

[Here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/02/14/loading-data-from-plist-files/) is a link on how to load data from the plist file onto the iPhone and [here](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?p=524) is a more in depth tutorial on creating the plist and loading it into the iPhone.

Comment: Thanks Carter - the tutorial link is exactly what I needed.